# Special values of Meijer G-Function

Tags: special-functions

We define a function
$$
f(k)=
G_{3,3}^{3,2}\left(1\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 -1,\frac{2}{k}-2,\frac{1}{k}-1 \\
 0,\frac{1}{k}-2,\frac{2}{k}-2 \\
\end{array}
\right.\right)
$$
where $G(\cdot)$ denote [Meijer G-Function](https://dlmf.nist.gov/16#PT4).

I noticed that for $k=2,3,4,6$, $f(k)$ has a simple form
$$
f(2)= \frac{1}{4} \left(4+\pi ^2\right), \quad
f(3)= \frac{2 \pi  \left(2 \pi  \sqrt{3}+3\right)}{9 \sqrt{3}}, \quad
f(4)=\frac{1}{4} \pi  (2+3 \pi ), \quad
f(6)=\frac{\pi  \left(5 \pi  \sqrt{3}+4\right)}{3 \sqrt{3}}
$$
But I could not figure out what $f(5)$ should be.

Does $f(5)$ also has a simple form?

Comment: Mathematica/Wolfram Dev Platform has that function. Have you tried the `Simplify` function on it?

Comment: Could you give me the Mahematica input form of $f(k)$. I am going to university today and they have the CAS. I could try.

Comment: Thanks, but l have already tried Mathematica. Now I believe there probably isn't a simpler formula for f(5)